# Transferring call from source Android phone to sink-audio development kit using Bluetooth?

Tags: android, audio, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I am trying to make an app in which I can transfer my call from Android phone (the *source*) to audio development kit (CSR 8670 Development-Kit as *sink*). I am able to transfer audio through A2DP profile but to transfer call I need to enable HFP in which I am still facing problem. Is there a proper way to transfer a call either by Bluetooth Hands-Free profile or A2DP profile?

Comment: It would be nice, if not helpful, if this was NOT tagged as an iOS CoreBluetooth issue. Not being an Android dev, I have no clue. The "core-bluetooth" tag is described by SO as "a framework for iOS and Mac OS X to interact with Bluetooth Low Energy ("BLE") accessories."